# Contour of integration

Tags: complex-analysis, math-software, programming

I am learning complex analysis and I would like to know what programs are the most appropriate for sketching the contour of integration? For example, I would like to sketch contour for integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln{x}}{(1+x)^3} dx$.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you'd like to plot?

Comment: @Botond For example, contour for integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln{x}}{(1+x)^3} dx$

Comment: You'd like to plot the $(0, +\infty)$ interval?

Comment: No, closed contour for that integral.

Comment: There is Wolfram Mathematica for that, but, it is not open source.

Comment: GeoGebra is free and is good for drawing simple figures like most integration contours.  However, I don't know a simple way to put arrows on arcs, as is common to show the direction of integration. https://www.geogebra.org/classic